# Closing the "list of files in a directory" when having Vim to open the directory

Tags: gvim, vim-windows

In the following screenshot, I demonstrate the following operations that shall yield a "buffer" that cannot be closed. My guess is that the list of files/directories is actually not a buffer. My question is: **how to close such a thing?** When I use `:bnext`, such a "buffer" always get in my way.

1. Open a "directory" by `vim ~` (this opened my home directory); ==> I then get the first "buffer" opened, displaying the list of files + directories in my `~` directory;
2. In the newly opened Vim session, edit (open) `.Xauthority` file by `:e .Xauthority`; ==> This brings up another buffer
3. Then, I close the new buffer with `:bd`.
4. Lastly, I tried twice to close the first buffer of all files+directories with `:bd`. ==> nothings gets closed.

I have been experiencing the problem all Vim installations that I have: on Windows machine as `gvim.exe`, on Linux machine through the commandline (this recording) and on Linux with `gvim` GUI sessions.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That “buffer” is netrw. It notoriously has this issue, although in practice it’s not a huge deal.

I tend to swap files by name or argument list (`:args`) more often than cycling through buffers.

In other words, don’t worry about deleting it, and don’t let it bother your workflow.